# UDP Broadcast not working with cross over cable

Tags: udp

I use the following code to braodacst UDP request. I have two network cards on the computer. One is connected to LAN and another is connected to another computer through a cable. So,my braodcast is working well on the LAN but its not on the cable directly connected to the computer. Could you help me?

My Code:

```
            Socket sending_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram,
            ProtocolType.Udp);

            IPAddress send_to_address = null;

            send_to_address = IPAddress.Broadcast;

            sending_socket.EnableBroadcast = true;

            IPEndPoint sending_end_point = new IPEndPoint(send_to_address, port);

            sending_socket.SendTo(buffer, sending_end_point);
```

Comment: What is `IPAddress.Broadcast`? If it's the general broadcast address `255.255.255.255`, it just sends to the default interface. You need to use a subnet-specific broadcast address to send to the subnet connected to that interface.

Comment: Yes. Braodcast means 255.255.255.255. Default interface means? I think I know what you're trying to say. So, if the IP address on that subnet is 169.35.67.2,then I should try to broadcast on 169.35.67.255?

Comment: The default interface is probably the interface associated with the default route, but I'm not sure; maybe it's just the first interface in the kernel's interface table. That's the correct broadcast address if your subnet mask is 255.255.255.0.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. Your suggestion worked. I just need to braodcast on that subnet.